# Where to include ngCordova in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am working on an Ionic app, and I have an issue. On ngCordova's website, they say we need to include the ng-cordova.js file **after** angular.js and **before** cordova.js

The problem is that I don't have those files in my Ionic project. I only have the files :

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

When I include cordova.js before these files, they say that angular is not there so the plugin cannot run. When I include it between the 2 files, or after them, I have no error. But then, when I inject ngCordova in my App, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core','starter.controllers','starter.services','ngCordova'])
```

or like this:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])
```

I get an error which says that the ngCordova plugin does not exist.

I ran the following command in my terminal:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git
```

And the ng-cordova.js file I use is the one provided by the website when I make a custom build.

Any idea of what the problem could be?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to worry about that, `ng-cordova.js` will be automatically added after building your application. please debug application after build, you will never find this message.

you just need to add `<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>` in `index.html` after `ionic.bundle.js` file.

if you are creating app using `ionic start appName` then this will be automatically added.

For more information read [this discussion](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/486)

Answer (score 1):

To install ngCordova please follow this [Document](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) in your project.

If you have bower then no problem if you don't have bower then try this command `npm install -g bower` after that follow this steps.

```
bower install ngCordova
```

and in your index.html

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

and then you can add as

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw this, but I wanted to install a custom build (because I don't need the whole thing), and I don't include the cordova.js file because it is included in the ionic files.

Comment: yes you dont need to include the cordova.js file the thing that i have posted is to show you that **ng-cordova.js** file path should be above the **cordova.js** file path

Comment: if you still get error try to download **cordova.min.js** file and include it in html and then include ngcordova  in your module. so that you can avoid using this steps.